# How to detect a memory leak

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-leaks, memorystream

I have doubts that this part of code causes memory leak:

```
    public FileResult ShowCroppedImage(int id, int size)
    {
        string path = "~/Uploads/Photos/";
        string sourceFile = Server.MapPath(path) + id + ".jpg";

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        var bitmap = imageManipulation.CropImage(sourceFile, size, size);
        bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        Byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
        return File(bytes, "image/png");
    }
```

How could I make a test to see if this piece of code is the cause?

EDIT:

```
public Image CropImage(string sourceFile, int newWidth, int newHeight)
        {
            Image img = Image.FromFile(sourceFile); 
            Image outimage;

            int sizeX = newWidth;
            int sizeY = newHeight;

            MemoryStream mm = null;

            double ratio = 0;
            int fromX = 0;
            int fromY = 0;

            if (img.Width < img.Height)
            {
                ratio = img.Width / (double)img.Height;
                newHeight = (int)(newHeight / ratio);
                fromY = (img.Height - img.Width) / 2;
            }
            else
            {
                ratio = img.Height / (double)img.Width;
                newWidth = (int)(newWidth / ratio);
                fromX = (img.Width - img.Height) / 2;
            }
            if (img.Width == img.Height)
                fromX = 0;

            Bitmap result = new Bitmap(sizeX, sizeY);

            //use a graphics object to draw the resized image into the bitmap 
            Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(result);

            //set the resize quality modes to high quality 
            grPhoto.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            grPhoto.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            grPhoto.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            //draw the image into the target bitmap 
            //now do the crop            
            grPhoto.DrawImage(
                img,
                new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight),
                new System.Drawing.Rectangle(fromX, fromY, img.Width, img.Height),
                System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);


            // Save out to memory and get an image from it to send back out the method.
            mm = new MemoryStream();
            result.Save(mm, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            img.Dispose();
            result.Dispose();
            grPhoto.Dispose();
            outimage = Image.FromStream(mm);

            return outimage;
        }
```

Comment: Simple way: rig your program to repeatedly call that code, then watch your process in Task Manager. If the memory used keeps rising and never drops, then you have a leak.

Comment: http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com.au/2010/11/determine-if-your-net-application-has.html

Comment: Only thing that you can do here is to wrap MemoryStream into an using block to dispose it automatically. Why do you think there is any memory leak. Please let us know what is inside imageManipulation.CropImage. Are you closing unmanaged handles ?

Comment: Please don't add stuff like " C#" to the ends of your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: And generally: every object that implements IDisposable should be wrapping in a `Using`; then you pretty much don't have to worry about memory leaks.

Comment: [You can't release the MemoryStream until you release the bitmap.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/522636/16623)

Comment: Did you try any profiler to profile a memory ?

Comment: @abhishek I think there is a memory leak because on shared hosting where my app is running from time to time app pool gets stopped. Since hosting provider can't/won't let me see events log their explanation is that my application probably has a memory leak that's causing the app pool to stop. After I restart it than it works fine. I really have no idea what to do in that case.

Comment: meh, the web host think its a memory leak... the web host must realize that starting with IIS6 the app pool gets recycled, and before it gets recycled a new instance spins up to take the requests. Hence if its stopping and not starting again and they say its your application then ask them to prove it, link to this SO thread too..

Answer (score 3):

I would write it as

```
public FileResult ShowCroppedImage(int id, int size)
{
    string path = "~/Uploads/Photos/";
    string sourceFile = Server.MapPath(path) + id + ".jpg";

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (Bitmap bitmap = imageManipulation.CropImage(sourceFile, size, size))
        {
            bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            Byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
            return File(bytes, "image/png");
        }
    }
}
```

to ensure that stream.Dispose & bitmap.Dispose are called.

Comment: The `using (MemoryStream = ...)` is just ritual, the using around the Bitmap seems more relevant.

Comment: Disposing of anything that implements IDisposable when you no longer need it is ALWAYS good practice. Doesn't matter if, in practice, it's only because other implementations need that ability; if it's IDisposable, dispose of it.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to call `stream.dispose();` after `Byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();`.

Answer (score 0):

Given the question was how to detect memory leaks/usage, I'd recommend writing a method that calls your function recording the memory usage before and after:

```
public void SomeTestMethod()
{
    var before = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
    // call your method
    var used = before - System.GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
    var unreclaimed = before - System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
}
```

Before will measure the memory usage before your function runs. The used variable will hold how much memory your function used before the garbage collector was run and unreclaimed will tell you how many bytes your function used even after trying to clean up your objects.

I suspect used will be high and unreclaimed will not - putting a using around your memory stream as the other posters suggest should make them closer although bear in mind you still have a byte array holding on to memory.